# Stata: Counts non-duplicate rows as duplicates

Tags: stata

Consider the following  code to detect duplicates, as from the [faq](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/duplicate-observations/):

```
. quietly by date id:  gen dup = cond(_N==1,0,_n)
. browse date id dup
```

and here's the output:

```
date            id    dup
360             1003    0
360             1005    0
360             1017    1
360             1017    2
360             1019    1
360             1019    2
360             1019    3
360             1023    1
360             1023    2
360             1023    3
```

I don't understand why the third row `(360, 1017, 1)` is a duplicate (`dup==1`)... it is the first row with id `1017`. What am I missing?

I'm on Stata 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused with the logic.

For each group, as determined by the variables used with the `by` prefix, if there is more than one observation, the count starts at 1 (see `help _n`). The variable `dup` for the last observation of the respective group you refer to (observation 4) states there are two observations that are the same:

```
360             1017    1
360             1017    2
```

Observations are marked with `0` if and only if no duplicates exist. For example, observation 2:

```
360             1005    0
```

Check the result of minimally modified code:

```
quietly bysort date id:  gen dup2 = cond(_N==1,0,_N)
list, sepby(date id)
```

and that may help you with the original formulation.

Answer (score 1):

You got what you asked for. If a combination of values is unique (occurs once only) then `_N` is 1 and the returned value is 0.

Otherwise `_N` is 2 or more for each group and duplicated (identical) observations are assigned values 1, 2 (and so forth, as appropriate).

Here, and elsewhere, duplicated (identical) observations are identified on the variables specified (here `id date`).